# knockout observable add some objects to observable array on top of output returned by the api

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
_self.CITIES = ko.observableArray([]);

        m_usp_doc.on("click", "#citySelection", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/webapi/api/?',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    _self.CITIES(jsonData);
                    _self.CITIES.push({ "a": "A", "b": "B" }) ;
                }
            });
```

The api returns me some output values like `'F','G',H'`.

I want to get this data from api and push hard coded `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"` above that.

So that model has `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 'F', 'G', 'H'`.

I tried it using `_self.CITIES.push()` and declaring these (`A` to `E`) when declaring observable but none works.

Can anyone tell how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate item View model and then create a new instance of that model every time you get a new object.Also If you would like to add them in front of your array, you may use unshift() instead of push(). 

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/130/

```
var MainViewModel = function () {
   var _self = this;
   _self.CITIES = ko.observableArray([]);
   _self.CITIES.push(new ItemViewModel({ "a": "F", "b": "G" ,"c": "H" , "d" : "I" , "e" : "j"}));

   self.ClickMe = function (){
     _self.CITIES.unshift(new ItemViewModel({ "a": "A", "b": "B" ,"c": "C" , "d" : "D" , "e" : "E"}));
   }
}

var ItemViewModel = function (data) {
  var _self = this;
  _self.Variable1 = ko.observable(data.a);
  _self.Variable2 = ko.observable(data.b);
  _self.Variable3 = ko.observable(data.c);
  _self.Variable4 = ko.observable(data.d);
  _self.Variable5 = ko.observable(data.e);
}
 ko.applyBindings(MainViewModel);
```